# How to use recursive function to generate an array of m-length strings using 4 chars

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

Using c++ on visual studio
I want a function that generates a string array, assuming that each string in this array has the length m, and the letters to be used in the string production are A, C, G, T.
For example
If m = 4, then the array should contain 4^4 items "64" just like {AAAA, AAAC, AAAG, AAAT, AACA, AAGA,AATA, ............., TTTA, TTTC,TTTG,TTTT}
I manged to get such array using nested for loops but I can not change m with nested for loops:

```
string AllPatterns [10000];
string n [4] = {'A','C','G','T'};
string tempPattern ="AAAA";
int count =0;
for(unsigned int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
 {
  for(unsigned int j=0 ; j<4; j++)
   {
     for(unsigned int k=0 ;k<4 ; k++)
     {
      for(unsigned int l=0 ;l<4 ; l++)
      {
        tempPattern[0] = n[i];
        tempPattern[1] = n[j];
        tempPattern[2] = n[k];
        tempPattern[3] = n[l];

        AllPatterns[count] = tempPattern;
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need a recursive solution, but I don't know how to do it.

I found a python code that can do something like what I need "https://ideone.com/fork/ZHO9OF", but I don't know how to write similar thing in C++. The python code as follows:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
A most frequent k-mer with up to d mismatches in Text is simply a string Pattern maximizing Countd(Text, Pattern) among all k-mers. Note that Pattern does not need to actually appear as a substring of Text; for example, as we saw above, AAAAA is the most frequent 5-mer with 1 mismatch in AACAAGCTGATAAACATTTAAAGAG, even though it does not appear exactly in this string. Keep this in mind while solving the following problem:

Frequent Words with Mismatches Problem: Find the most frequent k-mers with mismatches in a string.
     Input: A string Text as well as integers k and d. (You may assume k ≤ 12 and d ≤ 3.)
     Output: All most frequent k-mers with up to d mismatches in Text.

CODE CHALLENGE: Solve the Frequent Words with Mismatches Problem.

Sample Input:
     ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT 4 1
Sample Output:
     GATG ATGC ATGT
'''
 
#define kmers long 4
s = 'ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT'
motif_len = 4
motif_dict = {}
mismatch = 1
 
print('Sequence = ' + s)
 
#find unique k-mers in the sequence
for i in range(len(s)-motif_len):
 motif = s[i:i+motif_len]
 if motif not in motif_dict:
  motif_dict[motif] = 1
 else:
  motif_dict[motif] += 1
 
#1: generate a list of motif
motif_list = []
for k in motif_dict:
 motif_list.append(k)
print('Motifs found : '),
 
#2: check where the motifs are [wrongly commented]
dict = {}
input = s
ylist = []
for item in motif_list:
 motif = item
 results = []
 y = 0
 for n in range(len(input)-len(motif)+1):
  counter = 0
  sample = input[n:n+len(motif)]
  for i in range(len(sample)):
   if sample[i] == motif[i]:
    pass
   else:
    counter += 1
  if counter <= mismatch:
   results.append(n)
 
 dict[item] = []
 for value in results:
  dict[item].append(value)
  y += 1
 ylist.append(y)
 
print('\nProgram Output:'),
final_list = []
for item in dict:
 if len(dict[item]) == max(ylist):
  print(item),
  final_list.append([item, dict[item]])
#print('')
print(final_list)
 
n=0
for n in range(len(final_list)):
 for m in range(max(ylist)):
  f = final_list[n][1][m]
  final_list[n][1][m] = s[f:f+motif_len]
#for item in final_list:
 #for n in range(len(item[1])):
  #print(item[1][n])
  #define the consensus sequence -> to do but not necessary for this case
  #for k in range(len(dict[item])): final_list[item].append(dict[item])
#list founded k-mers
print('\nSample  Output: GATG ATGC ATGT')  #same values, different order. It doesn't matter
```

Comment: "but I can not change m with nested for loops:" Which is m?

Comment: @Amadeus - the length of the string (4, in the example)

Comment: @max66 Now I see it. My fault

Comment: This is an m-fold cross-product of a given set, a well-documented problem on line.  Do the appropriate searches.  Post again when you hit a blocking point.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Prune could you give me a link to such post, I could not find similar case, maybe because my english.

Comment: We're not supposed to perform individual research on SO.  However, if you look for the cross-product of two sets or arrays (*not* vector cross-product), you should get useful information.

Comment: Why do you "need" a recursive solution?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I want a recursive solution so that I don't need to write 10 nested for loops to generate a string array with strings of length m =10

Comment: @Yosaki: Actually, you can generalize the problem without recursion.  Search for iterative solutions; you can have your outer loop iterates the string position through the quantity of letters you need, while the inner loop iterates through the characters at that position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that is not tested but it should work with minimum effort also tempPattern should call the string construct with lenght `m`. I am using pow function so you should include the proper header files.

```
string AllPatterns [10000];
string n [4] = {'A','C','G','T'};
string tempPattern ="AAAA";
int count =0;
for(unsigned int i=0 ; i<pow(4, m); i++)
{
  for(unsigned int j=0 ; j<m*2; j+=2)
  {
    tempPattern[j] = n[i>>j & 0x11];
  }
  AllPatterns[count] = tempPattern;
  count++;
}
```

I fixed your code but still I believe you should change your mind you do not need to generate them the outer loop is enough for you and no need to save this huge amount of permutations.

EDIT:
Here is the complete code which I made sure it compiles and it is working!

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int m = 4;
  string AllPatterns [10000];
  char  n[4] = {'A','C','G','T'};
  string tempPattern ="AAAA";
  int count =0;
  for(unsigned int i=0 ; i<pow(4, m); i++)
  {
    for(unsigned int j=0 ; j<m*2; j+=2)
    {
      tempPattern[j] = n[i>>j & 0x11];
    }
    AllPatterns[count] = tempPattern;
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but it did not work, I tried this code and the array will not be filled with the m length strings this way.

Comment: @Yosaki, I had to compile it to make sure it is working. Why you are saying it is not generating all possible DNA motifs?

Comment: it can be compiled just fine, but when I try to run it, it return error "expression: string subscript out of range"

Comment: this is because I told you the tempPattern must be initialized with a string of length m

Comment: Also allPatterns array must be of length larger than 4^m elements.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this recursively would involve visiting every string.

```
void doGenerate(std::vector<std::string>& AllPatterns, const std::vector<char>& elems, std::deque<int>& state = std::deque<int>())
{
    // Base case -- generate the string for this specific state.
    if (state.size() == elems.size())
    {
        std::string str;
        for (auto&& idx : state)
            str.push_back(elems[idx]);

        AllPatterns.push_back(str);
        return;
    }

    for (std::vector<char>::size_type Index = 0; Index < elems.size(); Index++)
    {
        state.push_back(Index);
        doGenerate(elems, state);
        state.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Which can then be called like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> AllPatterns;
doGenerate(AllPatterns, { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' });
doGenerate(AllPatterns, { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'Q', 'R', 'S' });
```

Comment: thank you, but I am beginner, I don't know how this function work? 
or where I should define the array AllPatterns (in my code it was in the main function but now, I don't know where to define). I could not understand what the input it takes and the output method

Comment: You can just pass AllPatterns in as a reference. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I propose an heavily template-programming solution.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <char ...>
struct chL
 { };

template <std::size_t, typename = chL<'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'>>
struct genDnaStr;

template <std::size_t N, char ... Ch1>
struct genDnaStr<N, chL<Ch1...>>
 {
   template <char ... Ch2>
   static void func (std::vector<std::string> & vs,
                     chL<Ch2...> const & = chL<>{})
    {
      using u = int[];  // 'u' for 'unused';

      (void)u { ((void)genDnaStr<N-1U>::func(vs, chL<Ch2..., Ch1>{}), 0)... };
    }
 };

template <>
struct genDnaStr<0U>
 {
   template <char ... Ch2>
   static void func (std::vector<std::string> & vs, chL<Ch2...> const &)
    { vs.push_back( std::string{Ch2...} ); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::string>  vs;

   genDnaStr<5U>::func(vs);

   for ( auto const & s : vs )
      std::cout << " - " << s << std::endl;
 }
```

Unfortunately this works only if you know the length (`m`; `5` in the following example) compile time.

If you can use C++17, the `func()` method of the not-zero specialization (the `using unused` version) can be written (thanks fold expression and the power of the comma operator) simply as

```
   template <char ... Ch2>
   static void func (std::vector<std::string> & vs,
                     chL<Ch2...> const & = chL<>{})
    { (genDnaStr<N-1U>::func(vs, chL<Ch2..., Ch1>{}), ...); }
```

Comment: thank you, But I am a beginner, I don't know how to use template and struct, I've learnt about vectors hours ago. can this code be simpler? and can I get 'm' as integer input as it wont exceed 20? thank you again

Comment: @Yosaki - if you want to write c++ code, I suggest you to familiarize, as soon as possible, with structs/classes and templates. And sorry but unfortunately my example use a lot feature that are not exactly simple to explain to a beginner; I suggest you to revise my example when you're familiar with variadic templates, default templates arguments and struct/classes partial specialization. Anyway, the code works when `m` is known at compile time; you can write something `switch(m) { case 1:  genDnaStr<1U>::func(vs); break; case 2: genDnaStr<2U>::func(vs); break; ...`, but isn't a great solution.